# Is there a tool to generate "after macro" code?

Tags: c++, macros

Currently I'm looking at Boost, it's a good C++ library, however, using quite a lot macros such that sometimes it's unable to debug "step into" the C++ code.

I understand some macros couldn't be replaced, such as

```
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_II(~, a ## b)
```

, but most can be "expanded".

Is there a way to generate C++ code "after macros"?

Comment: `gcc -E` might help

Comment: Asking for such tool is explicitly _off-topic_!